# Gershgorin circle theorem and eigenvalues of matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

As a part of a series exercises I am doing right now to kill some time during Covid-19 outbreak (and thanks to my University teacher) I stumbled upon this problem:

Let $A:=(A_1|...|A_p)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ where horizontal vectors $A_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$ are normalised under $L_2$ norm. Let $b\in col(A)$, where $col(A)$ denotes spaces spanned by columns of matrix $A$, and $\tilde{x}$ be a solution of the linear system $Ax=b$. Let $I$ denote support of $\tilde{x}$, that means indices of rows, where said vector has non-zero values. Let $A_I$ be matrix, consisting of columns $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ and $sign(x_I^*)$ be a vector values given by $sign(x_i^*)$ for any $i\in I$.
By $M(A)$ lets denote $max_{i\neq j}\{|<A_i,A_j>|\}$
The aim is to prove this inequality:
$$||x^*||_0 \leq (1+1/M(A))/2 \implies \forall j \notin I: |A'_JA_I(A'_IA_I)^{-1}sign(x^*_I)|\leq 1$$

Some hints were given as follows:

1) Prove Gershgorin circle theorem for real eigenvalues. (Which I was able to do so)

2) Prove that the largest eigenvalue of $(A'_IA_I)^{-1}$ is smaller than $2/(M(A)+1)$

for which I will present my reasoning and place where I've got stuck:

We know that $(A'_IA_I)^{-1}$ is $n\times n$ matrix, which is positive definite and has real eigenvalues. So from 1) we know that any of its eigenvalues falls into interval given as $[Q_{i,i}-\sum_{j\neq i}|Q_{i,j}|,Q_{i,i}+\sum_{j\neq i}|Q_{i,j}|]$. But we can easly see that $Q_{i,i}=<A_i,A_i>$ is by definition equal to 1, and for other $Q_{i,j}=<A_i,A_j>$. Also we know that $ \forall i,j: |<A_i,A_j>|\leq M(A) $. Also $A'_IA_I$ has only positive eigenvalues and eigenvalues of $(A'_IA_I)^{-1}$  are equal to $1/\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A'_IA_I$. So equivalently we need to find smallest eigenvalue of $A'_IA_I$ and find its lower bound
 from 1). But here I've got a problem because I've got such system of inequalities: 
$$1-\sum_{j\neq i} |<A_i,A_j>|  \leq \lambda \leq 1+\sum_{j\neq i} |<A_i,A_j>|$$ or using $M(A)$

$$1-kM(A)  \leq \lambda \leq 1+kM(A)$$
where dimension of $A'_IA_I$ is $k\times k$ from where I can't come to desired form.

3) Use 2) to prove inequality in right hand side of implication.

Here I've also got stuck, as even assuming that 2) is proven, I can't connect how bound on eigenvalue might help me in proving given inequality, using left hand side of implication, no matter how hard I try to wrap my mind around this.

I would appreciate any help, hint or direction to follow in those cases, as I am stuck on them for about 2 days and I am unable to do any progress so far. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original exercise asks us to prove that
$$
\|x^*\|_0\leq\frac1{2M}+\frac12\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad|A_j'A_I(A_I'A_I)^{-1}\mathrm{sign}(x^*)|\leq1.
$$
I am going to prove a slightly weaker version of what needs to be proved, namely, the statement that 
$$
\|x^*\|_0\leq\frac1{2M}\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad|A_j'A_I(A_I'A_I)^{-1}\mathrm{sign}(x^*)|\leq1.
$$
I can't see how to do better than this. Perhaps you will have some idea. Perhaps the fact that $\|x^*\|_0$ must be an integer has something to do with it.

You have proved that 
$$
\|(A_I'A_I)^{-1}\|\leq\frac1{1-kM}.
$$
Now we use
$$
k=\|x^*\|_0\leq\frac1{2M},
$$
to infer
$$
\|(A_I'A_I)^{-1}\|\leq\frac1{1-kM}\leq2.
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\|A_j'A_I\|_2\leq M\sqrt{k},
\qquad\textrm{and}\qquad
\|\mathrm{sign}(x^*)\|_2\leq\sqrt{k},
$$
and hence
$$
|A_j'A_I(A_I'A_I)^{-1}\mathrm{sign}(x^*)|\leq\|A_j'A_I\|_2\|(A_I'A_I)^{-1}\|\|\mathrm{sign}(x^*)\|_2\leq2Mk\leq1.
$$